# decode speex encoded file with speexdec

Tags: ubuntu, speex

I want to decode a sample speex file with speex dev (provided by libspeex)

but, executing "`speexdec sample_file_name.spx`" command

caused this error:

```
cannot open /dev/dsp no such file or directory.
```

what should i do?

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: don't add c++ tag just because the file you are working on was created using a program written in c++. that would be the same as adding c++ to every question about windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[man speexdec](http://linux.die.net/man/1/speexdec) is your friend. The command will by default output the file to the sound card. Seems you don't have one on that machine? To decode to a file instead, try

```
speexdec sample_file_name.spx output_file
```